# After installing an env using yml my Anaconda install had issues. After reinstall of Anaconda the old env is still referenced

Tags: python, anaconda

Had a working Anaconda install.  I then installed a new environment (tf2) using yml.
The (tf2) environment worked but my Conda  failed to start Jupyter.
I reinstalled Anaconda and Jupyter is now failing because it is trying to reference the (tf2) env that was removed during the uninstall.

I get this error:

```
E 07:18:19.220 NotebookApp] Failed to run the command:
    ['C:\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf2\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\*username*\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-2c1646ef-3a70-4ac0-99b7-d1921d0f5de6.json']
```

How can I resolve this issue as my Jupyter notebook fails consistently now?